# AngularJS directives - how to convert $attrs["value"] into a boolean

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a directive I found on the Web:

```
<input icheck type="radio" ng-model="vm.isEmployed" value="true" /> Yes
<input icheck type="radio" ng-model="vm.isEmployed" value="false" /> No
```

And the directive goes like this:

```
function icheck($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function ($scope, element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            return $timeout(function () {
                var value;
                value = $attrs["value"];
```

The problem I am facing is that `$attrs["value"]` is always a `string`, but the property in my ngModel is a `boolean`.

I have tried with `eval` and `Boolean`. But I believe this is more a question related to AngularJS directives. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you've "tried many ways" why don't you share them in your question so that people trying to answer don't come up with thing you've already tried?

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why wouldn't `$attrs['value'] === 'true'` work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `ng-value` instead of `value`. From the documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D:

> ng-value should be used instead of the value attribute if you need a
>   non-string ngModel (boolean, array, ...).

So I changed the view to:

```
<input icheck type="radio" ng-model="vm.isEmployed" ng-value="true" /> Yes
<input icheck type="radio" ng-model="vm.isEmployed" ng-value="false" /> No
```

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate attribute:

```
value = $scope.$eval($attrs.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the truthy/falsy values to your tag to clarify things----

```
 ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'"
```

Comment: I found the right way to do it, but your answer was very insightful. Thanks!